# Using Powershell after attaching a database, how do you set logical names

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a standard vanilla database in a folder location, e.g. `MyDatabase.mdf, MyDatabases.ldf`. My PowerShell script is copying these files to the data folder of SQL Server, and renaming in the process, e.g. `MyProject.mdf, MyProject.ldf`.

I then attach the databases, however the logical names of both the original vanilla `.mdf` and `.ldf` remain. I am unable to figure out how to change these with PowerShell. I can do this with a restore, but wondering how with an attach.

```
$mdfFileName = "DataFolder\MyProject.mdf"
$ldfFileName = "DataFolder\MyProject.ldf"

$sc = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$sc.Add($mdfFileName)
$sc.Add($ldfFileName)

$server.AttachDatabase("MyProject", $sc)
```

An a test, I have tried

```
$db.LogFiles[0].Name
```

and this returns the logical name, however it is only accessible as a getter.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is missing a lot of functionality. It seems you are using SMO to work with the database. Why not use TSQL instead? It can be executed with `Invoke-SqlCmd`, or by using `System.Data.SqlClient` classes from .Net.

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyProject] ON
(FILENAME = 'some\path\MyProject.mdf'), (FILENAME = 'some\path\MyProject.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

Comment: Yes, I am using SMO. My current scripts are in TSQL, and yes, using Invoke-SqlCmd is an option, however I would like to know how it's possible using SMO in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the rename method to rename the logical file followed by alter method. You'll need to refresh your SMO object with refresh method afterwards to see the changes.